# xp_cmdshell write file directory to a text file

Tags: sql-server, xp-cmdshell

how do I write my file directory to a text file? The directory I want to use is C:\

The code I have now is

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'dir *.exe & echo > file_directory.txt';--
```

It's not writing to a file though. Do I need to say this...

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'cd c: \ & dir *.exe & echo > file_directory.txt';--
```

Comment: In case it becomes relevant, you can use the `/d` switch to change current drive in addition to changing current directory for a drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cd` (by itself) only sets the working directory, it won't change the working disk drive.  If you (may) need to change the working drive *and* working directory you need `pushd c:\` or `cd /d c:\`.

The easier solution is to fully-qualify the file name instead:

```
echo > c:\file_directory.txt
```

But it's generally not a good idea to write to the root of C:.  Microsoft has tried to make this harder, for the very good reason that opening up write privilege to the root of your system partition opens up all sorts of security risks.

(Update:)
I think what you want is

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'dir *.exe > c:\file_directory.txt';
```

Comment: I think what you want is
exec xp_cmdshell 'dir *.exe > c:\file_directory.txt';

You might also want to qualify where to perform the directory listing ie
exec xp_cmdshell 'dir c:\somepath\\*.exe > c:\file_directory.txt';

Comment: Does the dir *.exe only grab executable files? I need to the entire file directory of the C:\ drive.

Comment: The *.exe was in your original snippet.  If you want everything use exec xp_cmdshell 'dir c:\ > c:\file_directory.txt'; or exec xp_cmdshell 'dir c:\ /a > c:\file_directory.txt'; if you want to include system/hidden files.